# How to add Azure Active Directory authentication only to some Razor Pages in a web app?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I have implemented the Azure Active Directory authentication following [Azure AD Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004373/how-to-add-azure-active-directory-authentication-to-a-razor-pages-app)
on the Stackoverflow. In my project, I need the authentication only on the Settings page and the other pages to be available without any authentication. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?
I have a dedicated layout page for the Settings page which calls the `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure which pages to protect from unauthorised users as follows:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Settings");
    });
```

Comment: I made the change but I'm still getting the login prompt as soon as the site loads

Comment: Has your IndexModel got an `[Authorize]` attribute on it? If so, remove it.

Comment: No Mike, I do not have the `[Authorize]` attribute on any page.

Answer (score 1):

Found a working sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization/samples/3.x/AuthorizationSample)
Similar to **Mike Brind's** sample, here is the approach to exclude/include folders.

```
 services.AddRazorPages(options =>
 {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Private");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Private/PublicPage");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Private/PublicPages");
 });
```