# How to display parts of Razor Page depending on the Active Directory Security Group

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages project in which the `Index` page has a link to the `Settings` page. I want to allow access to the `Settings` page only for users who are part of the `APP-Administrator` security group in the Azure Active Directory. All the users who access the `Index` page are already **authenticated** on the Azure Active Directory.

1. How can I make the link to `Settings` page visible only to the users from `APP-Administrator` group.
2. How can I block non-admin users from accessing the `Settings` page directly using the URL (e.g. https://myapp.myorg.com/settings).

Note: This question is not related to [How to add Azure Active Directory authentication only to some Razor Pages in a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540121/how-to-add-azure-active-directory-authentication-only-to-some-razor-pages-in-a-w)

Comment: Have you tried [Authorize] on the controller?

Comment: I am not using MVC controllers in my project. I have built it as plain Razor Pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Azure Active Directory authentication only to some Razor Pages in a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540121/how-to-add-azure-active-directory-authentication-only-to-some-razor-pages-in-a-w)

Comment: No, I am looking to find a way where I can identify users belonging to a particular AD Group.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: Using a hybrid Razor Page web app hosted in Azure with a React front end. Some pages will be handled on the server while others will be only on the client via API’s hosted in APIM.  We have used the build in server side code to sign-in/sign-out

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
a class='@navItemCss' asp-area='MicrosoftIdentity' asp-controller='Account' asp-action='SignOut'

a class='flex' asp-area='MicrosoftIdentity' asp-controller='Account' asp-action='SignIn'

We can **utilize Authorization attributes on pages** and methods with custom policies around groups in Azure Ad.
[Authorize(Policy = 'Partner-Portal-Admins')]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I wrote a tag helper;

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "policy")]
public class PolicyTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService authService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public PolicyTagHelper(IAuthorizationService authService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.authService = authService;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string Policy { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (!(await authService.AuthorizeAsync(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User, Policy)).Succeeded)
            output.SuppressOutput();
    }
}
```

That way you can simply add a policy attribute to make that html disappear when the user does not have access.

```cs
<a asp-page="/Settings" policy="administrators" ... >Settings</a>

// Startup;

services.AddRazorPages(options => {
    options.Conventions
        .AuthorizePage("/Settings", "administrators");
});
```

The only remaining question, is how you identify adminstrator users, which might look like;

```cs
// Startup
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("administrators", policy => policy.RequireRole("[domain]\[group]"));
});
```